# Real-time screensharing to Java app (localhost)

Tags: java, swing, overlay, screensharing

I am looking for a way to add an overlay to a running **Windows** game, like [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) (a game streaming application, used for Twitch).

I though about using the `Robot` class to take 25/30 screenshots every seconds and display them, but I'm not sure that's the right solution..

So my question is the following: How can I *screenshare* a running app to a Java application (localhost, same computer), in order to add an overlay in front of it ?

**EDIT**: I tried using VLC Streaming but that makes the computer really laggy (i7/8Gb)... I tried with FFMpeg too, using `screen-capture-recorder` and `gdigrab`, the computer was not laggy, but the video drops like 5/10 FPS in real-time.

In FFMpeg, I used the following command : `ffplay -f dshow -f gdigrab -i title="<NAME>" -framerate 30`.

I would like to have a 25/30 FPS with a gaming computer (i7/8Gb)..

Comment: When you say `stream`, what exactly low level Java object are you referring as result? A constantly fed `InputStream` where you can read the frame data of from another thread/program?

Comment: I don't really care about the Java object type. It just has to be displayable in a `JPanel` :). The app is the client, and the server can be a 3rd party software (like VLC), or integrated in the app directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once developed [SimRat](https://github.com/rehrumesh/simrat) (A simple screen sharing app like Teamviewer) using Robot & Corba. You might be able to get a basic idea looking at the code. This is not the best possible way to implement screen sharing. Java RMI would be helpfull for you.

Comment: I tried some methods, and the screenshots using the `Robot` class looks like the fastest one in my case.. So I'll accept this answer ! Thanks :)

Comment: yeah... me too using openairplay, is one of the technique sharing screen as well.... but i wonder how the sound streaming become available ....

Answer (score 3):

Try [java-screen-recorder](https://code.google.com/p/java-screen-recorder/), it is a simple screen capturer and converter. It is not very cpu/gpu consuming. Solution based on `java.awt.Robot` and repeated capturing of the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure this tool lets the user to stream in real-time (I don't want to record the screen to a file and watch it later, but stream it)..

Comment: There are a lot of open source over internet! you can go further and connect screen-recoder with f.e. [Xuggler Streaming](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler)

Comment: If you think that should work, can you provide a source-code example that should run at 25/30FPS to stream an app ?